# Filtering to non-overlapping Ranges - Amazon RedShift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**Background:** I have ranges that are often updated to set prices for different amounts of materials. Once certain quotas are met, the prices are dropped. The problem is identifying the current prices after ranges have been updated or added.

I am looking to filter out non continuous ranges from a data set. Here is some test code:

```
drop table if exists public.test_ranges;
create table public.test_ranges (
    category        integer
    ,lower_bound    integer
    ,upper_bound    integer
    ,cost           numeric(10,2)
    ,modifieddate   timestamp
);

insert into public.test_ranges values (1,0,70456,0,'2015-09-29');
insert into public.test_ranges values (1,53956,60000,1.28,'2015-02-11');
insert into public.test_ranges values (1,70456,90000,1.02,'2015-09-29');
insert into public.test_ranges values (1,90000,120000,0.88,'2015-02-11');
insert into public.test_ranges values (1,120000,999999999,0.79,'2015-02-11');

insert into public.test_ranges values (2,0,48786,0,'2015-11-02');
insert into public.test_ranges values (2,22500,25000,0.43,'2015-02-17');
insert into public.test_ranges values (2,48786,50000,0.37,'2015-11-02');
insert into public.test_ranges values (2,50000,100000,0.21,'2015-02-17');
insert into public.test_ranges values (2,100000,175000,0.19,'2015-02-17');
insert into public.test_ranges values (2,175000,999999999,0.17,'2015-02-17');

insert into public.test_ranges values (3,0,585969,0,'2015-11-02');
insert into public.test_ranges values (3,346667,375000,0.15,'2014-09-12');
insert into public.test_ranges values (3,375000,500000,0.14,'2014-09-12');
insert into public.test_ranges values (3,500000,600000,0.13,'2014-09-12');
insert into public.test_ranges values (3,585969,999999999,0.02,'2015-11-02');
insert into public.test_ranges values (3,600000,670000,0.12,'2014-09-12');

select * from  public.test_ranges order by 1,2;
```

This code will return:

```
category  lower_bound  upper_bound  cost  modifieddate
--------------------------------------------------
1         0            70456        0     2015-09-29 
1         53956        60000        1.28  2015-02-11
1         70456        90000        1.02  2015-09-29 
1         90000        120000       0.88  2015-02-11
1         120000       999999999    0.79  2015-02-11 
2         0            48786        0     2015-11-02
2         22500        25000        0.43  2015-02-17 
2         48786        50000        0.37  2015-11-02
2         50000        100000       0.21  2015-02-17 
2         100000       175000       0.19  2015-02-17
2         175000       999999999    0.17  2015-02-17
3         0            585969       0.00  2015-11-02
3         346667       375000       0.15  2014-09-12
3         375000       500000       0.14  2014-09-12
3         500000       600000       0.13  2014-09-12
3         585969       999999999    0.02  2015-11-02
3         600000       670000       0.12  2014-09-12
```

The desired result:

```
category  lower_bound  upper_bound  cost  modifieddate
--------------------------------------------------
1         0            70456        0     2015-09-29 
1         70456        90000        1.02  2015-09-29 
1         90000        120000       0.88  2015-02-11
1         120000       999999999    0.79  2015-02-11 
2         0            48786        0     2015-11-02
2         48786        50000        0.37  2015-11-02
2         50000        100000       0.21  2015-02-17 
2         100000       175000       0.19  2015-02-17
2         175000       999999999    0.17  2015-02-17
3         0            585969       0.00  2015-11-02
3         585969       999999999    0.02  2015-11-02
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres?

Comment: Redshift........

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you saying that rows that are fully contained within other rows should not be displayed? What should happen if there is partial overlap between rows (eg 1-10 and 5-15)? Plus, I assume that the upper_bound value is not included in the range ("less than" rather than "less than or equal to")?

Comment: Hello John - I want to find only the next range that meets the previous range. For instance, if the range 0-15 is the start, the next range must be 15-x. A range of 11-X or 16-20 should be omitted. If its helpful, every category should start with 0 and end with  999999999.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it perfectly without recursive common table expressions. They are not supported currently in Redshift.

Partial solution (won't give you correct results for category 3):

```
select tr1.*
from  public.test_ranges tr1
  left join public.test_ranges tr_left on tr1.category = tr_left.category and tr1.lower_bound = tr_left.upper_bound
  left join public.test_ranges tr_right on tr1.category = tr_right.category and tr_right.lower_bound = tr1.upper_bound
where tr1.lower_bound = 0 or tr1.upper_bound = 999999999 or (tr_left.upper_bound is not null and tr_right.lower_bound is not null)
order by tr1.category, tr1.lower_bound;
```